# Como fazer para que o botão fique sempre a direita no topo dentro da div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function customAlert(customMessage)
{
    var interface = window.document.createElement("div");
    var button = window.document.createElement("button");
    var paragraph = window.document.createElement("p");
    var body = window.document.body;

    interface.style.width = "300px";
    interface.style.height = "200px";
    interface.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(80, 80, 80)";
    interface.style.position = "absolute";
    interface.style.left = "50%";
    interface.style.transform = "translateX(-50%)";
    interface.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    interface.style.overflowX = "scroll";

    button.textContent = "X";
    button.style.border = "none";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    button.style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    button.style.width = "30px";
    button.style.height = "30px";
    button.style.float = "right";
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
    button.style.borderRadius = "0 10px 0 0";
    button.style.outline = "none";

    paragraph.style.fontFamily = "arial";
    paragraph.style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    paragraph.style.position = "absolute";
    paragraph.style.left = "53%";
    paragraph.style.top = "40%";
    paragraph.style.transform = "translateX(-53%) translateY(-40%)";
    paragraph.style.fontSize = "14px";

    if (customMessage == "") {
        paragraph.textContent = "Está mensagem não diz nada!";
    } else {
        paragraph.textContent = customMessage;
    }

    button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function()
    {
        button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 90, 90)";
    });

    button.addEventListener("mouseout", function()
    {
        button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    });

    button.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        body.removeChild(interface);
    });

    interface.appendChild(button);
    interface.appendChild(paragraph);
    body.appendChild(interface);
}

customAlert();
```

Antes de tudo, sim fiz isso tudo com *JavaScript* e o arquivo é externo. Mas o que acontece o `button` ele não fica perfeitamente a direita quando o texto dentro do parâmetro `customMessage` começa aumentar. Se você executar `customAlert("E alguma coisa!");` no `console` veram que funciona perfeitamente, mas se for algo como `customAlert("sdededededededededededededededede");` o `button` começa a rolar junto com o texto e não fica mais a direita. Já testei quase tudo e ele não permanece a direita quem poder ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você teria que criar uma outra div pai e colocar o botão dentro dela, e não na div que faz o scroll e que contém o parágrafo.

Aí você terá também que alterar algumas propriedades. No exemplo abaixo eu criei a div `container` e coloquei a div `interface` dentro dela, assim como o botão, que ficou com `position absolute` posicionado no canto superior direito da div pai, algo assim:

```
---------- container ----------
|                     ------- |
|                     |botão| |
|                     ------- |
| -------- interface -------- |
| |                         | |
| |                         | |
| |    <p>parágrafo</p>     | |
| |                         | |
| |                         | |
| --------------------------- |
-------------------------------
```

```js
function customAlert(customMessage)
{
    var container = window.document.createElement("div");
    var interface = window.document.createElement("div");
    var button = window.document.createElement("button");
    var paragraph = window.document.createElement("p");
    var body = window.document.body;

    container.style.width = "300px";
    container.style.height = "200px";
    container.style.position = "absolute";
    container.style.left = "50%";
    container.style.transform = "translateX(-50%)";

    interface.style.width = "100%";
    interface.style.height = "100%";
    interface.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(80, 80, 80)";
    interface.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    interface.style.overflowX = "scroll";
    interface.style.position = "relative";

    button.textContent = "X";
    button.style.border = "none";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    button.style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    button.style.width = "30px";
    button.style.height = "30px";
    button.style.position = "absolute";
    button.style.top = "0";
    button.style.right = "0";
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
    button.style.borderRadius = "0 10px 0 0";
    button.style.outline = "none";

    paragraph.style.fontFamily = "arial";
    paragraph.style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    paragraph.style.position = "absolute";
    paragraph.style.left = "53%";
    paragraph.style.top = "40%";
    paragraph.style.transform = "translateX(-53%) translateY(-40%)";
    paragraph.style.fontSize = "14px";

    if (customMessage == "") {
        paragraph.textContent = "Está mensagem não diz nada!";
    } else {
        paragraph.textContent = customMessage;
    }

    button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function()
    {
        button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 90, 90)";
    });

    button.addEventListener("mouseout", function()
    {
        button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    });

    button.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        body.removeChild(container);
    });

    container.appendChild(interface);
    container.appendChild(button);
    interface.appendChild(paragraph);
    body.appendChild(container);
}

customAlert("1ahgashgsagashgashgashgashgashgashgahsghsaghasghasghasghasghagashgas0");
```

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo que eu queria, valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Visualizando por aqui, o botão nunca anda. Vi em 4 navegadores diferentes. Mas caso tenha problemas com o botão andando. Pode usar o position:absolute nele e tirar o float. Exemplo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f5j7xsk/)

```
button.textContent = "X";
button.style.border = "none";
button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
button.style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
button.style.width = "30px";
button.style.height = "30px";
button.style.position = "absolute";
button.style.right = 0;
button.style.top = 0;
button.style.cursor = "pointer";
button.style.borderRadius = "0 10px 0 0";
button.style.outline = "none";
```

Comment: O button ainda continua rolando com o texto, já tinha testando com o position sem sucesso.